# Blazor: How to play audio files in a table using HTML audio element?

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm making a table where files are loaded on in the browser. I want to select a file from the table by clicking on its file name, so that the audio element plays the selected files audio.

Right now I have a loop that goes through all files within a dirtectory, and shows the file names in the table cells on the left side. In the cells on the right side of the table there are multiple playable audio elements that correspond to the files whom have the name of the cells on the left side.

Here is the table:

```
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
    <tbody>  
        @if (filesList != null && filesList.Count > 0)
            {
                int auF = 0;
                @foreach (string file in filesList)
                {    auF++;
                     <tr> 
                         <td>
                             <span>@auF.</span>
                             <span @onclick="@(e=>readFile(file))" style="cursor:pointer;">@file</span>
                             </td> <td>
                             <audio controls="controls">
                                 <source src="@file">
                             </audio>
                        </td> 
                     </tr>
                }
            }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td>No files</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

code:

```
@code{
List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
string path = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\path"}";

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        filesList.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
}

public void readFile(string fileName)
{
}
}
```

How would I be able to have only one main audio element outside the table, such that when I select a file name,the audio element can play that selected audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use only one HTML `audio` player, you will need to create a custom component to include the audio element and perform the necessary logic whenever an audio file is selected from the table which include the following:

1. Resetting the audio player
2. Updating the audio `src` with the current `URL` of the selected audio
3. Autoplay the audio file

`MyAudioPlayer` Component:

```razor
<audio @key="@(audioId)" controls autoplay>
    <source src="@Url">
    Your browser does not support the html audio tag.
</audio>

@code {
    private string Url { get; set; }
    private Guid audioId = Guid.NewGuid();

    public void Reload(string url)
    {
        audioId = Guid.NewGuid(); // reload the player
        Url = url;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

Note:

- Don't forget to include the `namespace` of the component in the page.
- Store the audio files in `wwwroot` folder as web assets eg. inside `wwwroot\audio\` so that the audio player can access them by their url.
- Create a class eg. `AudioFile` to store the audio file properties such as the last modified date and file size to display in  table.

---

Implementation:

```razor
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp1.Components
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env

<MyAudioPlayer @ref="myAudioPlayer"/>

<table class="table table-striped mb-0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Modified</th>
        <th scope="col">Size</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (audioList.Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach (var file in audioList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@(audioList.IndexOf(file) + 1)</td>
                <td>
                    <a @onclick="@(() => myAudioPlayer.Reload(file.Url))"
                       class="link-primary"
                       role="button">
                        @file.Name
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>@file.LastModified.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm")</td>
                <td>@FileSizeFormatter.FormatSize(file.Length)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td>No files</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```cs
@code{
    MyAudioPlayer myAudioPlayer;
    readonly List<AudioFile> audioList = new();
    readonly string audioFolderName = "audio";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var path = $"{env.WebRootPath}\\{audioFolderName}\\";
        var d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = d.GetFiles();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            audioList.Add(new AudioFile
            {
                Name = file.Name,
                Url = $"/audio/{file.Name}",
                Length = file.Length,
                LastModified = file.LastWriteTime
            });
        }
    }

    public class AudioFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public long Length { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    }

    public static class FileSizeFormatter
    {
        static readonly string[] suffixes = { "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" };

        public static string FormatSize(long bytes)
        {
            var counter = 0;
            decimal number = bytes;
            while (Math.Round(number / 1024) >= 1)
            {
                number = number / 1024;
                counter++;
            }
            return $"{number:n1}{suffixes[counter]}";
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:
[image: Blazor audio element demo]

Comment: Thanks for this great sample Ibrahim.  It was just what I was looking for to get me started using the Audio control in Blazor

Comment: I implemented your great solution in Blazor and Maui Blazor.  I am unable to set video.currentTime in the Maui project.  I wonder if you could look at it and see if you can repo the bug.  [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059742/works-in-blazor-server-proj-but-not-in-maui-blazor-proj-html-audio-currenttime)