# Works in Blazor Server proj but not in Maui Blazor proj (html audio.currentTime += 10)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

Using html < audio > in Blazor pages.

Blazor Server project: Success at setting the audio.currentTime and audio.playbackRate.

Maui Blazor project: Success at setting the audio.playbackRate.

Maui Blazor project: **NO** success at setting the **audio.currentTime**.
Setting audio.currentTime sets the time back to ZERO.

Using the exact same code in each project except for pathing to the mp3 files.
The fact that setting playbackRate works tells me the javascript is wired correctly.

The example below uses 4 files:

- AudioPage.razor - Pages folder
- TpsAudioPlayer.razor - Component folder
- audio.js - wwwroot/js folder
- somepodcast.mp3 - wwwroot/audio folder

**AudioPage.razor**

```
@page "/AudioPage3"
<h3>AudioPage3</h3>

<TpsAudioPlayer @ref="tpsAudioPlayer" />
<br />
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @onclick="@(() => tpsAudioPlayer?.Reload(Url))">Load Audio</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @onclick="@(() => tpsAudioPlayer?.AddSeconds(10))">Add 10 Seconds</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @onclick="@(() => tpsAudioPlayer?.PlayBackRate(1.5))">1.5 Speed</a>

@code {
    TpsAudioPlayer? tpsAudioPlayer { get; set; }
    string Url { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //StackOverflow expert, Add an mp3 file to your wwwroot/audio folder.
        //I couldn't find any way to get the list of files in the wwwroot folder, so I pathed it out for this test.

        var folder = @"E:\source\DotNet\AudioPlayer\MauiAudio\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\wwwroot\audio";
        var d = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
        var files = d.GetFiles();
        Url = $"/audio/{files[0].Name}";
    }
}
```

**TpsAudioPlayer.razor - component**

```
@inject IJSRuntime js;

<audio @key="@(audioId)" controls autoplay id="audioplayer">
    <source src="@Url">
</audio>

@code {
    private string Url { get; set; }
    private Guid audioId = Guid.NewGuid();

    public void Reload(string url)
    {
        audioId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Url = url;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
public async Task PlayBackRate(double pbr)
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("playbackrate", pbr);
}
public async Task AddSeconds(double secs)
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("addseconds", secs);
}
        
}
```

**audio.js**

```
function addseconds(secs) {
    var ap = document.getElementById('audioplayer')
    //var ct = ap.currentTime;
    ap.currentTime += secs;

    //document.getElementById('audioplayer').currentTime = secs + ct;
}
function playbackrate(pbr) {
    var ap = document.getElementById('audioplayer')
    ap.playbackRate = pbr
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `async Task` in place of `async void`. Use `InvokeVoidAsync(..)` when your JS functions return nothing - like yours. Are you getting any error messages in the browser dev tools console?

Comment: Well I am getting this error, but I get the same error when I am speeding the audio up and that works.  Mixed Content: The page at 'https://0.0.0.0/AudioPage3' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'https://0.0.0.0/audio/hm883.mp3'. This request was not upgraded to HTTPS because its URL's host is an IP address.

Comment: I tweaked and changed above code to reflect your Task and Void suggestions.

Comment: Does changing secs to be `double` the same as pbr help?

Comment: Changed to double, but did not make a difference.

Comment: Setting audio.currentTime sets the time back to ZERO.  That might be a clue.

Comment: Try `ap.currentTime += parseFloat(secs)`?

Comment: parse did not work.  Interestingly, I clicked on the audio control to move the time forward and it does not work.  So obviously it's not the code?  Thanks for hanging with me on this Mr. M.  Other thoughts (see image above)

Comment: I think there are certain browser/audio type combinations where it cannot seek - does adding `?t=2` to the URL start the playback at 2s?

Comment: Well remember, this is now in a Maui App, so it is a windows app at this point.  It works perfectly fine in a Blazor Web App.

Comment: I have opened an issue with the WebView2 group over on github. [BugIssue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/3422)